# WPF: Binding and Commands

Tags: wpf, binding

My Customer has a property called SaveCommand.

My form is data-bound to an instance of the Customer object.

Using XAML, how would I bind Customer.SaveCommand to the form's save button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the form's DataContext has been set to the customer object

```
<Button Content="Save Button" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
```

or perhaps

```
<Button Content="Save Button" Command="{Binding SelectedCustomer.SaveCommand}" />
```